# Strange behavior of assertThat(actual).usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringAllOverriddenEquals().isEqualTo(expected)

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertj

I've come across an interesting behavior of recursive comparison in assertj library. If you compare objects of classes that are sub-classes, fields of super classes seem to be skipped during the comparison. Is that a known issue? Or am I doing something wrong? Here is a brief example:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class ExampleTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    MyException expected =
            new MyException("Expected text message");
    MyException actual = new MyException("Actual text message"); //values for the field Throwable.detailMessage are different
    assertThat(actual).usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringAllOverriddenEquals().isEqualTo(expected);
  }
}

class MyException extends RuntimeException {

  MyException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

This test will pass when actually it should not as `actual.getMessage()` and `expected.getMessage()` will show different values.

Comment: Why are you using both? They're kind of conflicting since one will do recursion on `equals` and the other will do recursion ignoring all `equals`.

Comment: They are not conflicting, but rather ```ignoringAllOverridenEquals``` is complementary to ```usingRecursiveComparison```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the lib skips comparison of the fields that are inherited from superclasses that reside in `java.lang`. As `MyException` is using a `detailMessage` field inherited from `java.lang.Throwable`, it is skipped. 
Here is the code from `org.assertj.core.internal.Objects` that seems to be responsible for such a behavior:

```
/**
   * Returns the declared fields of given class and its superclasses stopping at superclass in <code>java.lang</code>
   * package whose fields are not included.
   *
   * @param clazz the class we want the declared fields.
   * @return the declared fields of given class and its superclasses.
   */
  public static Set<Field> getDeclaredFieldsIncludingInherited(Class<?> clazz) {
    checkNotNull(clazz, "expecting Class parameter not to be null");
    Set<Field> declaredFields = getDeclaredFieldsIgnoringSyntheticAndStatic(clazz);
    // get fields declared in superclass
    Class<?> superclazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    while (superclazz != null && !superclazz.getName().startsWith("java.lang")) {
      declaredFields.addAll(getDeclaredFieldsIgnoringSyntheticAndStatic(superclazz));
      superclazz = superclazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return declaredFields;
  }
```

Comment: Have you found any alternative to include the `java.lang` superclasses ?
I have not found any.

Comment: @FlorianCousin Hi! Sorry for the very delayed response. No, I haven't, but back then I raised that question in their github project and got some explanations of why it is so: https://github.com/assertj/assertj/issues/1815 I hope this helps.